# OpsHub VS Online migration failed due to OH-TFS-Connector-0051 and the 'Board Column' field

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, opshub

I'm trying to migrate a fairly simple TFS repository to VS Online.  It would have started life under TFS 2012 and has been migrated to TFS 2013 and then, quite recently, 2015.

The migration is failing, just on user stories.  The error message is

> OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed createOrUpdateEntity. Server
>   Error : TF26194: The value for the field 'Board Column' cannot be
>   changed.

To the best of my knowledge we haven't created any fancy customisations and didn't make any use of Kanban boards in this project.

Many other items are also not migrating but these are all failing due to having a dependency on a user story.

In the status area I have

```
Work Item
- Reading and Analysis: Completed
- Migration: Failed
  1079 / 1176 Revision(s) passed
  97 / 1176 Revision(s) failed

Version Control
- Reading and Analysis: Not Running
- Migration: (?) Not Running
```

Any clues?

> Note (as per OpsHub comment requesting more information): Headline
>   version is 2015. Specific version is Version 14.0.24626.0. The failed
>   WorkItems are all user stories. Other WorkItems are also failing but
>   only because they are dependent on the user story WorkItems (according
>   to the OpsHub GUI)

Comment: Can you please post current TFS Version with Update level and WorkItem type for which you are getting this failure? You can get TFS version by clicking on Help Icon -> About on the TFS Web UI.

Comment: Sure.  Headline version is 2015.  Specific version is Version 14.0.24626.0.  The failed WorkItems are all user stories.  Other WorkItems are also failing but only because they are dependent on the user story WorkItems (according to the OpsHub GUI).   Thanks! :)

Comment: Some fields related to Kanban board like 'Board Column' are recently added in the TFS. Because of that utility is trying to migrate value of it but 'Board Column' is read only in VSO. Because of this it is giving error. It will get fixed in the next release of the OpsHub Utility.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Any idea when the next release may be out?

Comment: I see there's a v2.0 release.  I'll download and try that.

Comment: No. The fix will be in the release after v2.0.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks.  I just tried 2.0 before I saw your message and found it still had a problem.  Looking forward to 2.0.1 or whatever it will be :)

Comment: Current tentative date is by the end of this weak :)

Comment: Just saw 2.00.01 but the verification email part is broken.  It claims I'm not running the latest version and suggests I download 2.00.00 instead.  I'll try it again later.  Hoping this sorts it out :)

Comment: Hi Ian, Apologies, we are working to fix the verification issue. However, I am afraid, the Board Column fix is not a part of this release. We'll update you as soon as the release which has the fix is shipped.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to monitor.  I'll wait for a future release.  Cheers :)

Comment: Tried 2.0.2 - no luck still.    Error: OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed createOrUpdateEntity. Server Error : TF26194: The value for the field 'Board Column' cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the latest release (i.e. V2.0.0.003). While downloading from the MSDN gallery, make sure you are using link provided in the description.

Comment: Wonderful news.  I'll try it out later today.

Comment: Verified working.  I've got my project migrated.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to know :) For everyone else referring, with this fix, OVSMU is now officially supporting TFS 2015 Update 1 (where these new fields were added) as source.